# Member management for EE 3 and Cartthrob 3

Tags: cartthrob, devdemon, zoo-visitor

I am upgrading a EE 2 site with Carthrob to EE 3 with Cartthrob 3.  I had been using FreeMember to handle registration, logins, password resets and the like.

I see that FreeMember has yet to be ported to EE 3 by DevDemon.  I also see that they have acquired Zoo Visitor and updated it for EE 3.

In Cartthrob 3's documentation they say:

> Add-ons for member management
> In addition to using EE's built in member module, CartThrob is also compatible with Solspace User, Zoo Visitor, and our own product Profile:Edit. When Profile:Edit is installed CartThrob will can save customer data to your member channel entries automatically, in similar fashion to how it works with EE's member system.

Today, Cartthrob tech support responded to my question if DevDemon Visitor (and/or the new Zeal Smart Members) works with the current version of Carthrob by saying this:

> If Zeal and DevDemon Visitor use the standard ExpressionEngine member extension hooks, as Profile:Edit does, they should work properly with CartThrob. However, we haven't evaluated them to see; if there's a way to trial Visitor I'd definitely suggest that.
>
> Unfortunately Profile:Edit hasn't been updated for EE3 yet, and we don't have a timeline for doing it (and may not). So it's definitely worth looking at the other options!

I am wondering if anyone knows if DevDemon Visitor uses the standard member extension hooks?

Also, given that Cartthrob's documentation says that it is compatible with Zoo Visitor, am I right to guess that DevDemon Visitor is compatable with Cartthrob 3?

Comment: Did you resolve this, if so would you mind sharing the end solution?

Answer (score 1):

I am developer of [zeal smart members](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zeal-smart-members).

We have made plugin to make sure it uses the default ee methods for member registration, profile update etc.

It will call the default code while submit form and thus, default ee hooks can be use here.
You can find documentation [here](https://opensource.zealousweb.com/expressionengine/smart-members/).

Comment: Can you clarify one thing: does your plugin also hook into the EE default registration hooks? If someone registers a member outside of your code (with code that calls the default EE registration flow), does your code still see that and take the appropriate action on the entries?

Comment: No our code will not handle anything outside or our module. But it will trigger `cp_members_validate_members` and `member_register_validate_members` hooks to manage the proper action when need.

Can you give me an example of what you need?

Comment: Hello, did you resolve this, if so would you mind sharing the end solution?

Comment: This is resolved in zeal smart members and zeal smart members pro.